# Invalid SRID return from PostGIS ST_Centroid Function

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'd like to get the centroid of a set of polygons with `SRID 4326`

I start from this simple query to verify the `ST_Centroid` function

```sql
CREATE TABLE test AS
SELECT ogc_fid, geom, ST_Centroid(geom) centriod_geom 
FROM s_table
```

However, when I check the SRID of two geometry columns in the `test` table, it appears the SRID of `centriod_geom` changes to 0.

```
SELECT Find_SRID('public', 'test', 'geom');
SELECT Find_SRID('public', 'test', 'centriod_geom');
```

| geometry column | find_srid |
| --- | --- |
| geom | 4326 |
| centriod_geom | 0 |

What should I do if I need the `centriod_geom` to be 4326?

Comment: What version of PostGIS?  The intended behaviour is that functions keep the SRID in created geometry.  This is fixed in recent versions.

Comment: I am currently using version 3.1.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PostGIS implements type specific meta information (*geometry type* & *SRID*) via the PostgreSQL *typemod* system catalogues; a *typemod* adds specific constraints to (base) types, and cascades their restrictions to e.g. columns. Without specifically adding these constraints to the extension types (`GEOMETRY/GEOGRAPHY`), their defaults (`SRID = 0`) will be assumed.

When constructing geometries in a query, you will have to **explicitly cast them with their desired *typemod* constraints** to be recognized in the system catalogues (which are used by e.g. the `geometry_columns/geography_columns` *Views*, and functions like `Find_SRID`):

```
CREATE TABLE test AS
  SELECT ogc_fid,
         geom,
         ST_Centroid(geom)::GEOMETRY(POINT, 4326) AS centriod_geom 
  FROM   s_table
;
```

---

Note that having more than one geometry column *may* lead to issues with GIS client software.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly.